# What app is making my phone vibrate, without putting a corresponding notification up?

Tags: iphone, notifications, vibrate

There is an app I can't locate that is constantly making my phone vibrate. When it does, I immediately check the Notification Center. Nothing new there.

The vibrate could be a setting for an email application, or some other app.

One thing to note, I always have my app on silent/vibrate.  I just unmuted it in the hopes that the sound will help me figure out what is going on.

**Question**

How can I determine which app is sending rogue vibrations without any notification?

Comment: Email is my guess. The default settings for that over time have evolved.  I had this problem too, email was the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to go through **Settings** → **Notifications** and check which apps have an **Alert Style** of *None* and **Show in Notification Center** *disabled*, but **Sound** toggled *on*.

Comment: I have LOTS of apps.  Very painstaking to do...